# mean and variance of this Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am trying to read through this paper - http://www.malcolmdshuster.com/Pub_2002c_J_scale_scan.pdf

Equation 2(b)from the paper says

[A] 
$\nu_k \equiv 2(B_k - b).\epsilon_k - |\epsilon_k|^2 $

where

[B] $\epsilon_k$ is white and Gaussian.
Meaning, $\epsilon_k \sim N(0,\Sigma_k)$

The authors then say,

$\nu_k \sim N(\mu_k,\sigma_k^2)$                        ---- (1)

where

$\mu_k \equiv E\{\nu_k\} = -tr(\Sigma_k)$               ---- (2)

and
$\sigma_k^2 \equiv E\{\nu_k^2\}-\mu_k^2 = 4(B_k-b)^T\Sigma_k(B_k-b) + 2(tr\Sigma_k^2)$                                        ---- (3)

How are the authors deriving (1),(2) and (3) based on [A] and [B]?

Specifically,
(1) has to do something with the fact that $\epsilon_k$ is Gaussian but I've forgotten the properties, any pointer to this is helpful.
and I'm drawing a blank on how the *Expected Value* of $\nu_k$ is the trace of covariance matrix of $\epsilon_k$.

Comment: the one dimesional:

$$E[ax+b]=aE[x]+b$$
$$ var[ax+b]=a^2var[x]$$

and also:

sum of gaussian is also a gaussian, I mean

let X1,X2 be the Gaussian, then X1+X2 is a Gaussian with $G(\mu_1+\mu_2, ZZZZZ)$

if X1 and X2 be uncorrelated then, ZZZZZ = var$(X_1)$+var$(X_2)$